# AppBarLayout with FrameLayout container as scrolling content doesn't work

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm trying to use the newest design library to make my toolbar hide/show on scroll. My issue is the scrolling content I have is in the fragment, I'm just injecting it into the FrameLayout container and it doesn't work. Here's my activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_container"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_nav_drawer_anon" />
```

and my fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:color="@color/dark_grey"
    android:padding="60dp"/>
```

and toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
style="@style/Widget.MyApp.ActionBar" />
```

I'm following official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) and this [demo](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/), and still can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: Can you please provide us with more info? Like what you want to achieve and how you wants view/fragment to be stuctured.

Answer (score 26):

Replace your FrameLayout with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

> NestedScrollView is just like ScrollView, but it supports acting as both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions of Android. Nested scrolling is enabled by default.

[Link to doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView.html)

Comment: That only works if you want your entire fragment to be scrolled vertically. It does not work e.g. when your fragment contains a ViewPager that needs to coordinate with other children of the CoordinatorLayout. It seems that CoordinatorLayout doesn't work well with Children that are added via FragmentTransactions at a later time if the FragmentContainer is not a NestedScrollView. Sadly using a NestedScrollView is no option if the entirety of the fragment should NOT scroll vertically but otherwise react to swipe gestures.

Comment: Currently `androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView`. Add it above or replace `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 15):

Using FrameLayout as child of CoordinatorLayout works quite well. The toolbar is collapsing like it's supposed to. I had a problem in the beginning, when I used outdated libraries.

Here are the gradle dependencies I'm using right now:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

I'm using `FrameLayout` with the attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` as a child of `CoordinatorLayout` in an activity's layout. The `FrameLayout` serves as container for fragments. My fragment layouts' root elements are either a `RecyclerView` or a `NestedScrollView`.

Here is the layout of the activity:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/..."
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_height="192dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            >
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                >
            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/.."
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    android:src="@drawable/..."
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_sessions"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My first fragment's layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="..."
    />
```

My second fragment's layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="..."
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="..."
    >
...
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 12):

The reason for that behaviour is that the Framelayout doesn't specify a Behaviour. The CoordinatorLayout relies on the child view to handle the Behaviour.

You can read at the bottom here

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

It states that

> **CoordinatorLayout and custom views**
>
> One thing that is important to note is that CoordinatorLayout doesn’t
>   have any innate understanding of a FloatingActionButton or
>   AppBarLayout work - it just provides an additional API in the form of
>   a Coordinator.Behavior, which allows child views to better control
>   touch events and gestures as well as declare dependencies between each
>   other and receive callbacks via onDependentViewChanged().
>
> Views can declare a default Behavior by using the
>   CoordinatorLayout.DefaultBehavior(YourView.Behavior.class)
>   annotation,or set it in your layout files by with the
>   app:layout_behavior="com.example.app.YourView$Behavior" attribute.
>   This framework makes it possible for any view to integrate with
>   CoordinatorLayout.

Edit: Although FrameLayout is not a custom view, it doesnt specify a behaviour which CoordinateLayout seeks.

Comment: `The reason for that behaviour is that the Framelayout doesn't specify a Behaviour`. Thank you. This really helped.

Answer (score 4):

In my app it works only with RecyclerView. Maybe you should use RecyclerView instead of ListView.

Comment: Do you have RecyclerView in activity or fragment?

Comment: @wwang Just tested, it doesn't work with ListView. In my app, I have fragments with RecyclerView which works seamlessly and to test I added a Fragment with a ListView which failed to work.

Comment: So you mean only RecyclerView can be used to cause showing/hiding of the app-bar ? And that ListView can't?

Comment: @wwang  u resolved your issue using recyclerview ? i need to show /hide top layout once user start scrolling recyclerview or listview then again it comes down on scrolling down ..... how wil i solve here is question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32716906/issues-with-coordinator-layout-in-android

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve scrolling with Framelayout inside your CoordinatorLayout. For it you have to use  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside your `frameLayout` as well as inside the scrolling view with which you want this collapsing effect.

For ex- If you are inflating RecyclerView inside your frameLayout, then you have to use  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` inside your recyclerrView also.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
</Relativelayout>
```

or,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">
 <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bNext"
        android:fillViewport="true"
           android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<!--  your content -->
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</Relativelayout>
```

Thus, using this process you can achieve scrolling with frameLayout whether it contains recycler or nestedScrollview.

Comment: I know its little bit late to answer, but I resolve my problem this way

Answer (score 2):

It's a good question. I too had the same.

Your container `FrameLayout` is defined right the problem lies with the `Fragment`. The `Fragment` should have `RecyclerView` & not `ListView` as it is now deprecated.

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
```

I use the same structure in my app & it works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

ListView does not implement NestedScrollingChild so it does not work.

RecyclerView does, so it can propagate the scroll to the NestedScrollingParent (the CoordinatorLayout).

Comment: Is it possible to make ListView implement this interface, and make it work?

Comment: I think yes. Take a look at the RecyclerView's code and try to implement it in a custom ListView class. I've not tried it yet, so keep us updated if you success !

Comment: I've tried to use it for a while, but I didn't succeed in the given time. Please let me know if you succeed.  I've also tried to use this library to have this ability: https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView , but I failed making them work well together.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to replace

**FrameLayout**

to

**android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView**

in this way:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="192dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/header"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- This was before FrameLayout -->
    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_drawer_alertas"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` from the toolbar to the Framelayout. Sorry for being late.

Comment: but it can influence list scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

You must add behavior to the scroll view:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_main"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvUserProfile"
    app:recyclerviewEmptyView ="@layout/ev_home"
    app:recyclerviewClipToPadding="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></com.marshalchen.ultimaterecyclerview.UltimateRecyclerView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```