# issues with coordinator layout in android ?

Tags: android, listview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-tablayout

i m  using coordinator layout to achive this video [VIDEO REQUIREMENT](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x32inr5_instagram-requireemnt_creation)

NOW here is my layout :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/tabanim_maincontent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProfileImageSection"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutProfileImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profileImage"
            android:layout_width="110dip"
            android:layout_height="110dip"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_image_margintop"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_image_marginleft"
            android:background="@drawable/llayout_bk"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llayout_detail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/profile_rightside_layout_marginleft"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_username_margintop"
                android:text="sdsdsd"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_follow"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/follow_btn"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_follow_margin_top"

                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewLocationProfileName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:text="sdsds"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_editprofile"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="3dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/profile_edit_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_edit_margin_top"
            android:background="@drawable/edit_btn"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
<View
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/profile_tablayout_margintop"

    />


    <com.ui.MyTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
        />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

but the issue i m getting this type result  [image: issue image] it should show all items in  a listview in vertical order while right now there are 5 items in listview but they are in limited length adn inside limited height i can see more items on scroll how to avoid ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using `AppBarLayout` and `CollapsingToolbarLayout`?

Comment: actually i already have actionbar in fragment and i m doing same procdeure in whole app so i will be using actionbar while what do u think  CollapsingToolbarLayout  will fulfill my issue

Comment: I only wonder because I'm currently building an app that uses a collapsing toolbar, `TabLayout` and a `NestedScrollView` that will eventually house a `RecyclerView`. [Here is a fairly recent demo video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygzWY4QsrwEa2RUU0hzclhGcFU/view) - if you think it will help, I can post an answer with a link to an example I used as a template, and few of my own adjustments.

Comment: @PPartisan  can u pls check this demo will this work if  i use in fragments and actionbar inside fragment i will be using custom actionbar in fragments and viewpager and tabs

Comment: @PPartisan  pls post answer and all related files i have layout ....

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a layout similar to the one posted in your demo video, which involves a collapsing toolbar, `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` I would recommend using the following gist as a guide:

[CollapsingToolbarLayout with TabLayout](https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea)

If you experience any issues with the fragments loaded into your `ViewPager` not correctly wrapping content, then you can try the following:

1. Use this [gist by TheLittleNaruto](https://github.com/TheLittleNaruto/SupportDesignExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/thelittlenaruto/supportdesignexample/customview/WrapContentHeightViewPager.java) and use it to replace `anroid.support.v4.view.ViewPager` in your layout `xml`. This custom `ViewPager` will wrap child contents, and so is ideal for `ListView` and `RecyclerView` content.
2. **Or, if you would instead like the `ViewPager` to occupy any remaining space and not simply wrap content:** Inside the `Activity` class where you retrieve your `AppBarLayout` and `ViewPager`, and an `AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener` to your `AppBarLayout`, and use it to adjust the height of your `ViewPager` so that its size adjusts to occupy the space below your `AppBarLayout`:

`Activity` class:

```
//Class variable
private int windowHeight;
//...
@Override
public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int offset) {
    if (windowHeight == 0) windowHeight = getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
    int appBarHeight = (int) (appBarLayout.getHeight() + appBarLayout.getY());

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) mViewPager.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = (windowHeight - appBarHeight);
    mViewPager.setLayoutParams(params);
```